# speech recognition software for typesetting advanced math symbols

Tags: number-theory, math-software

Does anyone know of a sophisticated speech recognition software program for typesetting of math symbols used in Number Theory research? I am aware of MathTalk (which is used along with Dragon Naturally Speaking) for people with mobility problems, but don't think it is advanced enough for Number Theory research. I don't see any similar type of program out there which is more advanced.  I am inquiring for a family member who currently  cannot use hands due to Repetitive Stress Injury (acquired because of constant math/keyboarding). Ideally the program would "recognize" spoken math formulas/symbols and produce the proper visual symbols.

Comment: Use LaTeX, then you can simply say backslash (proper LaTeX command) and write up papers.

Comment: Thank you!  Will try it!

Comment: I'm new to this site, so not sure this is the way to clarify.  But isn't there some kind of software that needs to be installed in order to activate speech recognition on LaTeX?  Looking online I see various approaches, such as installing "Talon", and using it along with Dragon?  I presume it's not built in to LaTeX itself.  Speech  recognition technology is rapidly changing, so I don't know what is the most up to date method.  There are several older posts online (3-5 yrs old), but I presume there is newer technology in 2021.

Comment: Most simple latex commands are simple words like pi, phi, sum, sigma, delta, alpha, beta, in fact most variables and exponents subscripts should be easy. Personal dictionary may help but shouldn't be required.